# Finding differently lengthed time intervals between two dates

Tags: php, date, datetime, intervals

I want users to be able to select a date range and an interval to display results from, such as "show me results between Jan 1, 2017 and Apr 1, 2017, listed by day|week|month"

So if they selected day, I'd group results by Jan 1, 2017; Jan 2, 2017; Jan 3, 2017; etc...

If they selected week, it'd be Jan 1, 2017; Jan 8, 2017; Jan 15, 2017; etc...

The method I'm using now is as follows:

```
if(isset($chosenInterval) && ($chosenInterval == "week" || $chosenInterval == "day") ) {
    $timeFormat = "F j, Y"; 
} else {
    $timeFormat = "F Y";
    $chosenInterval = "month";
}

$start    = (new DateTime($start))->modify('first day of this month');
$end      = (new DateTime($stop))->modify('first day of next month');
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 '.$chosenInterval);
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

foreach($period as $dt) {
    $dataLabels[] = $dt->format($timeFormat);
}
```

The problem is that if the user selects Jan 8, 2017 - Jan 20, 2017, it still includes all the dates in January.

Ideally it would show:

- Day: Jan 8, 2017; Jan 9, 2017; ... Jan 19, 2017; Jan 20, 2017
- Week: Jan 8, 2017; Jan 15, 2017
- Month: Jan, 2017

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: Any particular reason why you don't want to set `$start` and `$end` to the start and end dates chosen?

Comment: @Aydin not really, I'm not very familiar with the DateTime objects and so I lifted the code off another thread that was similar. I tried to remove the modify portion but ran into an error somewhere so I abandoned the idea. Doing that does get me closer, though I ran a test where I did Aug 7, 2017 - Sep 7, 2017, with a month interval, and I only got August back -- not September also. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check when adding your `DateTime` objects to `$dataLabels` if the date is before the start or after the end. If it is (and the `$chosenInterval` is not a month), don't add them:

```
<?php
$start = "2017-01-08";
$stop = "2017-01-20";
$chosenInterval = "week";
function getDates($start, $stop, $chosenInterval = "week") {
    $startDT = new DateTime($start); // make a DateTime out of the date to later compare it
    $stopDT = new DateTime($stop); // make a DateTime out of the date to later compare it
    if(isset($chosenInterval) && ($chosenInterval == "week" || $chosenInterval == "day") ) {
        $timeFormat = "F j, Y"; 
    } else {
        $timeFormat = "F Y";
        $chosenInterval = "month";
    }

    $begin    = (new DateTime($start))->modify('first day of this month');
    $end      = (new DateTime($stop))->modify('first day of next month');
    $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 '.$chosenInterval);
    $period   = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

    foreach($period as $dt) {
        if ($chosenInterval !== "month" && ($dt < $startDT || $dt > $stopDT)) continue; // if date is before start or after end, skip
        $dataLabels[] = $dt->format($timeFormat);
    }
    return $dataLabels;
}
var_dump(getDates($start, $stop));
var_dump(getDates($start, $stop, "day"));
var_dump(getDates($start, $stop, "month"));
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/bZnIM)